# How to pass value from java to .js file and get turned result in .html?

Tags: javascript, java, html

I am working in a application. I needed to call local HTML from javafx that html using .js and in .js contains hard coded value for creating chart.

How to pass numeric value from Java to .js by which create a desired chart in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

A quick approach would be, given that you serve the html file with javafx:
Through javafx, write this line to the html file:

```
<script>window.desiredNumber= {the desired number from java} </script>
```

Now it is accesible in any scope of javascript served with the html because we have put it in the global scope (window). 
To use the value within for example a function you would do:

```
graphfunction(window.desiredNumber)
```

But it would be nice to specify at the start of the js file that you rely on the global scope to get a value and do the following:

```
var desiredNumber = window.desiredNumber;
```

Comment: In HTML I am getting 'data' which pass from java. data is an array of object. now its required to pass this 'data'  to "data" property in Morris chart. Please help

Comment: @PradeepKumarSoni If you want further help it will be necessary that you post some code of the java and the html.